# Simulink PID block vs derivative/integrator

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm making a PID model in Simulink, but I'm having an issue. In the image below you can see I tried two different methods: using the PID block directly and using gains with derivative/integrator blocks. Why are these producing the two very different results shown in the second image? Using the PID block agrees with the result I get from rltool. Thank you.

[Simulink Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESvcj.png)

[Result to Step Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zHsN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the derivative is not consistent between the built-in PID block and your PID controller. If you click into the PID block, you will see that it does not use a pure derivative, but instead an approximation which provides rolloff at high frequencies. The derivative approximation in the PID block is:

[image: \frac{du}{dt}\approx\frac{N}{1+N\frac{1}{s}}=\frac{s}{\frac{1}{N}s+1}]

with a default value of N=100. The use of a step input (which technically has an infinite derivative) results in a pronounced difference between the two implementations when `Kd` is nonzero.

If you replace the derivative block in the bottom implementation with a transfer function block that has the same coefficients as the derivative approximation, the output will be identical to the result using the PID block.

Comment: I did [this](https://imgur.com/d3DRJp7) and it worked perfectly.